# Name the Book / Movie / Show

Tags: cipher, rebus

What book / movie / show does the following refer to?

`&#x1f44d; {F52C090C-D3BE-48EA-AE49-6BCCF449A561}2.718 2 Winter Street`

Comment: I got half of it, allowed to post as partial answer ?

Comment: Sure; though please use spoiler text (`>! your text here`) to ensure no one sees any part of the solution accidentally.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers

Comment: cant get the >! part working on all parts of my partial answer

Comment: @SvenB I tried to edit your post as well, and couldn't get it to go either.

Comment: @SvenB: this may help in future: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72877/whats-the-exact-syntax-for-spoiler-markup

Answer (score 15, accepted):

&#x1f44d;

> Code for the thumbs-up icon, or in this case, a link to a **hitchhiker** (who'd show his thumb to signal passing motorists he wants a ride).

{F52C090C-D3BE-48EA-AE49-6BCCF449A561}

> Is a random globally unique id, short: **GUID**

2.718

> Mathematical constant **e**

2

> Pronounce as **to**

Winter Street

> Or in swedish: Vintergatan, a name for the Milky Way **galaxy**

Thus the final answer is

> Hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy

Comment: dangit! Beat me to it

Comment: I had one hint wrong though, updated now.

Comment: ahhhhh nicely done. I couldn't figure out how winter street was the galaxy part

Comment: It took some meta-googling ("winter street galaxy") to find :)

Answer (score 5):

Partial solution

```
&#x1f44d;
```

> is the thumbs up icon.

```
{F52C090C-D3BE-48EA-AE49-6BCCF449A561}
```

> can be split in parts of 4 which refer to (chinese ?) symbols combined with button U (some examples)
> - [f52c](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f52c/index.htm)
> - [090c](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/090c/index.htm)
> - [d3be](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d3be/index.htm)
> - [48ea](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/48ea/index.htm)

2.718

> might refer to [the base of natural logarithms](http://www.mathamazement.com/Lessons/Everyday-Math/05_Miscellaneous/05_03_Important-Numbers/base-of-natural-logarithms.html)
>    also called e

Comment: Good work; though `{F52C090C-D3BE-48EA-AE49-6BCCF449A561}` has a different purpose here.